Is the alternating group of degree infinity a normal subgroup of symmetric group of degree infinity?
In my exam today, I was asked to prove or disprove the following statement: for an infinite set $X$, there exists a non-trivial proper normal subgroup of $Perm(X)$.
Discussion with my friends after the exam revealed that the answer is likely the subgroup that consists of permutations of $Perm(X)$ that moves finitely many elements in $X$. However, during the exam, the subgroup I came up with was the alternating group of degree infinity, which has index 2 in the symmetric group of degree infinity and hence normal in $S_{\infty}$. I am not sure if it fits the conditions of the question. Is it correct?

The group of all bijections from an infinite set $X$ to itself has as a nontrivial normal subgroup the set of permutations of finite support (permutations that move only finitely many elements of the set $X$), and the subgroup of that subgroup of even permutations of finite support. Also, if $X$ is uncountable, the set of permutations with support of cardinality at most $\kappa$ for any infinite  cardinal $\kappa\lt|X|$.

What is $S_\infty$? How do you define the alternating subgroup?

@ArturoMagidin Thanks! So ultimately we have to in some way link it to the subgroup of finite support in Perm(X).

@MoisheKohan Hmm it's the group of all permutations on an infinite set. And I defined the alternating subgroup as its subgroup of even permutations

But the question is what is a "permutation" on an infinite set (vs. a bijection from the set to itself). Are permutations necessarily of finite support? Or do they have to have finite orbits? What does it mean for a bijection that moves infinitely many elements of $X$ to be even? Hence the questions.

See here and references cited there.

These are very interesting questions indeed! @ArturoMagidin This is my first course in group theory, and I am constantly being intrigued by whatever we've learnt so far

The notion of an even permutation is meaningless if the set is infinite, unless the permutation has finite support. And you should use consistent notation: Instead of $S_\infty$ it should be $Perm(X)$ as elsewhere in your question.

@MoisheKohan I had the impression that $Perm(X)$ and $S_{\infty}$ are isomorphic when $X$ is infinite

$S_{\infty}$ is usually the direct limit of the $S_n$, which gives the permutations of finite support. Different things whenever $X$ is infinite. Also, while $Perm(X)$ or $Sym(X)$ would keep track of the cardinality if $X$, even if $S_{\infty}$ was supposed to represent all bijections, how do you distinguish between, say, the group for $X=\mathbb{N}$ and the one for $X=\mathbb{R}$?

@ArturoMagidin That's true. The question didn't specify whether $X$ was countable or uncountable

I expect this has appeared here previously, but there is a result classifying all normal subgroups of the symmetric group ${\rm Sym}(X)$ on an infinite set $X$. For a proof, see for example Theorem 8.1A of the book "Permutation Groups" by Dixon and Mortimer.
The nontrivial proper normal subgroups consist of the group of all even permutations of finite support, usually denboted by ${\rm Alt}(X)$ and, for each infinite cardinal ${\mathbf c} \le |X|$, the group of all permutations with support less than ${\mathbf c}$. So, for $X$ infinite, there is no normal subgroup of index $2$.
In particular, when $X$ is a countable set, there are just two proper nontrivial normal subgroups, the group of all permutations with finite support, and ${\rm Alt}(X)$, an infinite simple group.

Indeed, you gave the same answer in 2012.

@ArturoMagidin So I see (although the question was slightly different), and I got 32 upvotes for that answer, so I should have remembered it!
